# Do I need to be proficient with Alchemy Supplies to cast Healing Elixir?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, unearthed-arcana, spell-components, proficiency

[Healing Elixir](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/UA-Starter-Spells.pdf) is a new spell from Unearthed Arcana Starter spells for my character (fighter 4 warlock 2)

I am concerned because *Alchemy Supplies* is listed under the material components for the spell.

I know that in order to use Alchemy Supplies you need to be proficient with them because they are listed as an Artisan Tool. Do I need to be proficient in Alchemy Supplies in order to use the spell Healing Elixir or is it a different kind of Alchemy Supplies?

Comment: I don't think you need proficiency to use artisan tools.  According to the player's handbook, it just allows you to add your proficiency bonus to ability checks using the tools.

Comment: Edited to add the Unearthed Arcana tag to enable other users to locate the question more easily or to screen out UA content questions.

Answer (score 5):

## One only needs to have access to a set of Alchemist's Supplies*

"Alchemist's Supplies" seems to be the same as the artisan tool, but you don't need to be proficient in them in order to use it as a material component for the spell.

Material components act as a sort of focus (different than your casting focus) and are not consumed, unless the spell states otherwise.

Note:
*I believe that by RAW, a component pouch or spell focus does away with the requirement for Alchemist's Supplies, as the spell does not list a cost for them.

Comment: I think you can be more definitive about the material component bypass for a pouch/focus here.

Comment: @NautArch Can I? Alchemists Supplies have a definitive cost outlined in the equipment section, so I wasn't sure the interaction.

Comment: Hmm. Probably worth another question :) But many components have a cost, but if the cost isn't dictated in the materials itself, then I don't think it counts. But worth asking. I'll put something up.